# Coupon code for whole cart not applied to multiple items

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, coupon-codes

**What it should do:**
A coupon code which provides a discount of 5 € on the whole cart, if the subtotal equals or is greater than 40 €.

**What it does:**
It works fine with one article (even multiple units of that article), but when I put different articles in the cart, the discount is indetermined lower.

Actions:
[image: Magento Settings of Cart Price Rule Actions]
Conditions:
[image: Magento Settings of Cart Price Rule Conditions]

Comment: What are you using as your conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution now:

This is a  [known bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/products/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67/) in Magento CE 1.9, you can use this extension to fix it temporarily: [Shopping Cart Price Rule Fix](https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix).